# How can I shuffle around property in an object based on a condition

Tags: javascript, object

JSBin: 
https://jsbin.com/kuwivohixu/edit?html,js,output

```
var v = {
    checkit: {
    'company_dummy': {
        count: 0
    },
    'company_2': {
      count: 1
    },
    'company_3': {
      count: 1
    },
    'company_4': {
      count: 6
    },
    'company_5': {
      count: 6
    }
  }
}

var newest_company = "company_5";
var company_sorted = [];
for (var each_company in v['checkit']) { //for each company in 'v'
  company_sorted.push([each_company, v['checkit'][each_company]]); //save the company and the company object in affinity
}

company_sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[1]['count'] - a[1]['count'];
});

/*
company_sorted.sort(function(a,b) {
  //How can I update my object that if the `newest_company` has a count
    that is tied with another company as the higest `count` then move 
    that to be the first in the group after being sorted from high to low

})
*/

console.log('company_dummy' in v['checkit']);
console.log(company_sorted);
```

How can I update my object that if the `newest_company` has a count
        that is tied with another company as the higest `count` then move 
        that to be the first in the group after being sorted from high to low

Comment: Why don't you just use an array?

Comment: It was already coded and changing would mean changing in places I have no idea about unfortunately :/

Comment: Object properties have no order, so you cannot rearrange them.

Comment: @RickHitchcock So I can't say if this property count is tied with another property (maybe more than 1) and the count is the highest for all the property move this property to the beginning of the group? I mean I am already sorting from high to low already.

Comment: @rick he's still having an array?

Comment: You'll need to change to an array if you want the structure to be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the company to the company you need if the count is equal:

```
/* v (bad name) and newest exist */
const companies = Object.entries(v.checkit);

companies.sort(([nameA, objA], [nameB, objB]) => 
 objB.count - objA.count ||
 (nameA === newest_company) - (nameB === newest_company)
);
```

Comment: so I had `company1: 5` `company2: 5` `company3: 4`. The `newest_company` was `company2` and it didn't move it before `company1`

Comment: @Si8 what if you set `newest_company` to `company1` ? (Maybe I messed up the ordering)

Comment: I will do some testing and shuffle around the "shuffling around" and see if that may work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.keys`like so :

```
let companies = []
Object.keys(v.checkit).forEach(c => {
   if (c !== newest_company)
      companies.push({name: c, count: v.checkit[c].count})
})
companies.sort((a, b) => { return b.count - a.count})
for (let i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
   if (v.checkit[newest_company].count >= companies[i].count) {
      companies.splice(i, 0, {name: newest_company, count: v.checkit[newest_company].count})
      break;
   }
}
if (!companies.length) companies.push(v.checkit[newest_company])
v.checkit = companies
```

NB: this solution transform your checkit properity into an array

Comment: Ok I think I can work with that. I will try it out thanks

Comment: There is an issue with this script as if there is only one entry in `v.checkit` then `companies` stays blank.

Comment: @Si8 i've just updated my answer; if the object contains only the newest_company then it will return an array containing the newest_company. I've also ordered the companies from top to bottom (higher count values at the beginning)

Comment: Thank you let me try it out.

Comment: You know what that solution may work... :) I will implement it and get back to you. I appreciate your help